# How to insert date into minibuffer, or how to create a new file with date as part of filename?

Tags: minibuffer, filenames

shell way:
`` touch testfile-`date +%Y-%m-%d` ``

emacs way? `c-x c-f testfile-`... now what?

I want to type the first part of the filename myself, but not the date.

Comment: Try here, as a start: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertingTodaysDate.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Good. You can accept your own answer, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by adding this to my config:

```
(defun insert-current-date () (interactive)
  (insert (shell-command-to-string "echo -n $(date +%Y-%m-%d)")))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'insert-current-date)
```

Comment: Instead of starting a shell and running `date`, consider using a cheaper method: `(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")` returns the same string as `(shell-command-to-string "echo -n $(date +%Y-%m-%d)")`. It hardly makes a difference in this case because there is no repetition  (it took 1/10 sec in one case vs a few microseconds in the other on my machine), but looking for a better way to do something is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Typo: 1/100 of a second, not 1/10.